# Run 1 thread at time with ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, executor

I'm developing a review extractor for the Play Store, using Selenium. My piece of code is the following:

```
public void extract() {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(this.configurationManager.getNumberOfThreadToUse());

    for (String currentApp : appsToMine) {
        ArrayList<String> aux = new ArrayList<>();
        aux.add(currentApp);
        Crawler googlePlayStoreCrawler = CrawlerFactory.getCrawler(this.configurationManager, aux, "google");
        executor.execute(googlePlayStoreCrawler);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

Here, `Crawler` implements `Runnable`. Using more than on thread, where each one open a separated instance of Firefox, Selenium fails because the web page is not visibile (it is hidden by a new windows opened by the another thread). So, I'm trying to execute all the process with only 1 thread at time.

But also if I instantiate an `ExecutorService` using `newFixedThreadPool` with 1 as parameter, a new threads always starts when the previous is running.

Comment: Does your app end after one and only one call to this `extract` method? Is there any further work in the app or is this methods its only job?

Comment: `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);` will return a thread pool with only 1 thread, so any tasks submitted to this pool will run sequentially. If this is not a case for you, then there is a mistake somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you don't need to use threads at all. Just run the crawler via the main thread:

```
for (String currentApp : appsToMine) {
    ArrayList<String> aux = new ArrayList<>();
    aux.add(currentApp);
    Crawler googlePlayStoreCrawler = CrawlerFactory.getCrawler(this.configurationManager, aux, "google");
    googlePlayStoreCrawler.run();
}
```